# Get SVG path d attribute using path id

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have separate json containing SVG path Ids. Is there a way to get SVG path 'd' attribute using path id? Or is there a way to fill SVG path only using path Id?

Comment: Please upload the SVG , and mention which element exactly you are trying to get so we can give you some insights.

Comment: @RobertLongson works perfectly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the path element by calling document.getElementById and from there you can get/set attributes...

```
var d = document.getElementById("<path id>").getAttribute("d");

document.getElementById("<path id>").setAttribute("fill", "red");
```