# Getting an element from a <path> from a svg path in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to get svg path string out of svg path in html.
Ler's suppose I have a svg Path in this format.

```
<path d="M 0 68.5 C -1.56977e-13 30.6685 184.011 -1.30814e-14 411 -3.92443e-14 C 637.989 -5.23258e-14 822 30.6685 822 68.5 C 822 106.332 637.989 137 411 137 C 184.011 137 -1.56977e-13 106.332 0 68.5 Z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="none" stroke="none"></path>
```

How can I get the value inside **path** tag, specially value inside **d** attribute.

There is one way to get it by doing some basic operation like getting index of M and fill, but that is not a very good solution for this.

```
        var htmlStr = elem.outerHTML;
        var start = htmlStr.indexOf("M");
        var end = htmlStr.indexOf("fill");
        var str = htmlStr.substring(start, end);
        str.replace("\"", "");
        str.trim();
```

Can anybody suggest some generic solution for this?

**Note: path tag does not have any Id, and I can't create one as it is coming from other service.**

Comment: Stop messing around with the HTML representation of the element, and use DOM methods instead. `elem.getAttribute('d')`

Comment: document.getElementById works for SVG. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48485411/12057512

Comment: I don't have pathId here, It is coming form a service, which I can't make change. –

Comment: Well is it the only path? I.e. how do **you** know it's the right path? We could tell you how to find the first path in the file for instance.

Comment: I am getting it as output of some service call.

Answer (score 1):

You can juste use the [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) of path like that :

```js
const pathId = document.getElementById("pathId");
const dValue = pathId.attributes["d"].value;

console.log(dValue);
```

```html
<path id="pathId" d="M 0 68.5 C -1.56977e-13 30.6685 184.011 -1.30814e-14 411 -3.92443e-14 C 637.989 -5.23258e-14 822 30.6685 822 68.5 C 822 106.332 637.989 137 411 137 C 184.011 137 -1.56977e-13 106.332 0 68.5 Z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="none" stroke="none"></path>
```

Comment: You need to do document.getElementById("pathId") before you can get its attributes. "pathId" is not a variable, it's an ID.

Comment: It's work without but I changed it. Thanks you.

Comment: I don't have pathId here, It is coming form a service, which I can't make change.

Comment: You can use the querySelectorAll and make a while for get every attributes you want.

Comment: Do you have the id to the path's parent? Because then you could potentially iterate through all the parent's children, using document.getElementById("parentid").children. Edit: Pioupia's idea is better. Ignore mine.

Comment: ``pathId.getAttribute("d")``